# MATCH function does not work with words that have wildcards (*)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I am trying to match **`HA24BB-3-1LL`** with **`HA24B*-3-1**`** in Excel. Another example is matching **`HA24FB-3-1LL`** with **`HA24F*-3-1**`**.

However, when I performed the regular match function, these could not be matched.

```
   col A             col B
1  HA24BB-3-1LL      HA24F*-3-1**
2  HA24FB-3-1LL      HA24B*-3-1**
```

What I tried:

```
=MATCH(A1,B:B,0)
```

It should return 2 but it returns `#N/A`.

May I know why?

I thought Excel match function works with wildcard. Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: You have the lookup value and lookup array switched. Try `=MATCH(A:A,B1,0)`

Comment: Yep, you're doing it backwards. You can use wildcards in the string you're *looking for* but the strings in the array/range being searched will be treated as literals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match with wildcards, but the wildcards have to be in your lookup value (first position in the formula). If they are in the lookup array (second position in the formula) they are not wildcards, just literal `*`s in the cell values.

So you can find matches to strings like `HA24B*-3-1**` in your first column by using the formula: `=MATCH(B1,A:A,0)`, but not the other way around, as your formula is set up.

Also, if you are looking for things that match `HA24B[one character]-3-1[two characters]` your search string should instead be `HA24B?-3-1??`. The `*` will match a string of any length, so it is redundant to put two of them at the end of your search string, and using them will also find you matches to strings like `HA24Babcdedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-3-1abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`. Which may be what you want, and if it is leave it as is (minus the second `*` at the end). The `?` matches a single character, which I am assuming is what you are looking for since you used `**` in your question.

Comment: Just to add, for OP, [here's](http://trumpexcel.com/2013/11/tame-the-wildcard-characters-in-excel/) a site that has Excel wildcards with how to use them. (and obviously you can [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=excel%20wildcards) for more).

Comment: Many thanks guys. This is very useful. It solved my problem.